# Laravel 5.5 - CSS File couldn't found

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

CSS File path is true but still couldn't found..

CSS File Path;

> public/assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.css

In Blade;

```
 <link href="{{asset('assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Where do I mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

the second **assets** shouldn't be needed if your css is in **resources/assets**.

```
 <link href="{{asset('demo/default/base/style.bundle.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```